# Can two ASP . NET Core 5.0 web api cause "The content may be already have been read by another component" errpr 400 if they accessed same db be4?

Tags: flutter, content-management-system, asp.net-core-5.0

My API was as follows:

```
[HttpPut("{id}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<HomeContextModel>> EditHomeContext(int id, string title, string context, string subcontext, IFormFile imageFile)
    {
        HomeContextModel homeContextModel = await _context.HomeContext.Include(x => x.Image).Include(x => x.Button).Include(x => x.Logo).ThenInclude(y => y.Image)
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Context_Id == id);
        //HomeContextModel homeContextModel = await GetHomeContextModel(id);

        if (homeContextModel == null)
        {
            return BadRequest("Context Id cannot be null");
        }


        if (imageFile != null)
        {
            ImageModel imageModel = homeContextModel.Image;
            if (imageModel != null)
            {
                string cloudDomain = "https://privacy-web.conveyor.cloud";
                string uploadPath = _webHostEnvironment.WebRootPath + "\\Images\\";

                if (!Directory.Exists(uploadPath))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(uploadPath);
                }

                string filePath = uploadPath + imageFile.FileName;

                using (var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
                {
                    await imageFile.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
                    await fileStream.FlushAsync();
                }

                using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    await imageFile.CopyToAsync(memoryStream);
                    imageModel.Image_Byte = memoryStream.ToArray();
                }

                imageModel.ImagePath = cloudDomain + "/Images/" + imageFile.FileName;
                imageModel.Modify_By = "CMS Admin";
                imageModel.Modity_dt = DateTime.Now;

                //_context.Update(imageModel);
            }

        }


        homeContextModel.Title = title;
        homeContextModel.Context = context;
        homeContextModel.SubContext = subcontext;

        _context.Entry(homeContextModel).State = EntityState.Modified;

        try
        {
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
        {
            if (!HomeContextModelExists(homeContextModel.Context_Id))
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            else
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        return Ok("Home Context Edit Successfully");

    }
```

It's an API for the Content Management System (CMS) to change the content of the Homepage using a Flutter webpage that make put request onto this API.

Everything works fine. In the last few days, where I tested and tested again during the development. So before today, I've wrapped up them and submitted to the necessary place (It's a university FYP).

Until now it cause me this error when I was using this to prepare my presentation:

```
Error 400 failed to read the request form Unexpected end of stream ..."
```

[image: Error message]

After all the tests I tried:

- Internet Solutions
- restore the database
- repair Microsoft VS 2019 (As this issue was fixed before after I
  updated my VS 2019 from 16.8. to the latest 16.11.7)
- Use the ASP .NET file which didn't cause this issue before

Then I realized it may be because I used another older ASP file to access the same database before. Does this really cause this matter?

If yes, then now how should I solved it, with the action I already done (listed as above)?

**EDIT: Additional description to the situation**

The above API I set breakpoint before, on the first line, using Swagger to test it.

It turns out that it didn't go into the API and straightaway return the error 400

Answer (score 0):

REST API can have parameters in at least two ways:

- As part of the URL-path
  (i.e. `/api/resource/parametervalue`)
- As a query argument
  (i.e. `/api/resource?parameter=value`)

You are passing your parameters as a query instead of a path as indicated in your code. And that is why it is not executing your code and returning 400.